# Force Facebook sharing debugger meta - Wordpress to purge cache

Tags: wordpress, facebook, meta, sharing

I searched over the web and still could not find a solution. 
I used Yoast SEO on my WordPress to make sure I got all the Meta codes that Facebook need. 
One of the articles in my website work just fine, I'm not sure if there is any difference between the two articles code wise.

the tool by iframely show the following: http://iframely.com/debug?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flyttd.com%2Fus-flight-training-part-1%2F

This is the current meta code display on the webpage:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="DqxdD4X3ZGn" />
<meta property="og:title" content="קורס טיס אזרחי בארה״ב – חלק א׳ - טוּס אֶת הַחֲלוֹם" />
<meta property="og:description" content="פריסת התשתיות המתקדמות, המרחב האווירי הפתוח לרווחה, ואינספור שדות התעופה מכל הסוגים והגדלים, הופכים את אמריקה לגן שעשועים לטייסים. רק כאן תוכלו לפגוש באותו היום ובאותו השדה מבנה של מטוסי קרב, ספינת אוויר, ומטוס קרגו של אמזון, תו״כ שאתם מנסים להנחית את הצסנה המצ׳וקמקת שלכם על המסלול הנכון. וולקם טו אמריקה!" />
<meta name="description" content="פריסת התשתיות המתקדמות, המרחב האווירי הפתוח לרווחה, ואינספור שדות התעופה מכל הסוגים והגדלים, הופכים את אמריקה לגן שעשועים לטייסים. רק כאן תוכלו לפגוש באותו היום ובאותו השדה מבנה של מטוסי קרב, ספינת אוויר, ומטוס קרגו של אמזון, תו״כ שאתם מנסים להנחית את הצסנה המצ׳וקמקת שלכם על המסלול הנכון. וולקם טו אמריקה!" /><meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.flyttd.com/us-flight-training-part-1/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="טוּס אֶת הַחֲלוֹם" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.flyttd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/catvot-300x162.jpg" />
```

Which is created by the following code in a functions.php

```
//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
    }
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//Lets add Open Graph Meta Info

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="DqxdD4X3ZGn"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . ' - טוּס אֶת הַחֲלוֹם"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . get_the_excerpt() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . get_the_excerpt() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="טוּס אֶת הַחֲלוֹם"/>';
    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image="https://www.flyttd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/mylogo.png"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else{
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

Facebook debugger codes:

```
Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a ticket with the Facebook support team, they scrape it on their end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the problem and i assured you, i did nothing with code as yoast seo does the work for Facebook sharing. The issue that i had was the featured image title description was not set properly. At first facebook did not had a strict policy on api for sharing, now facebook api want everything perfect.

Before 
[image]

After i set the title,Caption,Alt text & Description properly to salman then the facebook accepted my blog post for sharing "
Please try and let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help. All the picture are with proper title, caption, alt text, and description. When I use another website to check the meta code it looks like it caches the updates but for some reason facebook "scrape again" button won't work.

Comment: Have you enabled "Add Open Graph meta data" for facebook in yoast seo? and can you see the social sharing preview from yoast social tab below blog post in editor mode ?